# Viewing mp4 files in Firefox

Tags: ubuntu, firefox, mp4

I'm trying to embed an mp4 file in a `video` and `object` element, however it's failing to play/register - I wasn't able to find any sort of plugin so far. It would be great if someone could recommend some Firefox 3.5/Ubuntu Jaunty compatible plugin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ended up using jwplayer, all you do is basically reference a swf and pass any media file and it'll play it.

http://www.longtailvideo.com/players/jw-flv-player/

```
<script src="swfobject.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var s1 = new SWFObject("mediaplayer.swf","single","1280","544","7");
    s1.addParam("allowfullscreen","true");
    s1.addVariable("file","file.mp4");
    s1.addVariable("stretching","exactfit");
    s1.addVariable("smoothing","false");
    s1.addVariable("wmode", "direct");
    s1.write("player1");
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

https://developer.mozilla.org/En/HTML/Element/Video says it only supports ogg theora so far. maybe an addon can do it, but i couldn't find any

Comment: Yeah, I researched that and came to the same conclusion.